# STM32 MCU dead- Unconfigured pin supplied with voltage?

Tags: hardware, stm32f4

I have a PCB design which is based on the STM32F7 microcontroller(MCU). On of the pin(Port F Pin 2) of the MCU is always connected to a 3.3 volt line (the same line that powers the MCU up too). The MCU was flashed with a program and it showed the required behaviour but after a period of about 10 minutes of the it working there was fault that was detected, the voltage supplying the MCU was folding back. This on further inspection turned out there is a short between the gnd of the MCU and the power line that has developed. Upon the fault the firmware was checked and it was noted that the pin which was supposed to be set as a input was left unconfigured- the pin was left without assigning any state(Reset_State). Is this a possible reason for the MCU to have failed?[The state that the pin was left in the firmware that was connected with 3.3 power line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0mKY.png)

To find the short on the PCB board a thermal camera was used and at a slightly higher current limit the MCU was seen to be heating up. This is the reasoning used to assume that the MCU is the point of failure.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and possible electrical solution), what exactly is the purpose of a power line connected to GPIO pin directly without any resistor at all?

Comment: It was to read as a input to identify the mcu - there are two in the design (the other mcu has the same pin connected to gnd). This was done to have a same firmware flashed in the mcus but run different routines when required.

Comment: Yeah, it preferably requires hardware change. There is literally no reason to have power line connected directly to the GPIO pin, in fact it's inadvisable and unnecessary. Pull up the pin via 10k resistor to 3.3V, on the other MCU 10k to GND (this one is optional, but better have it for flexibility). There was no need to have power line connected to GPIO in the first place. With 10k resistor you will still have a firm GPIO HIGH level, but regardless of software configuration, it will be plain impossible to damage anything via 10k, even if you accidentally turn that pin to output and output low

Comment: Anything in range 3.3k-10k will work perfectly well out there, limiting worst case sink current (GPIO configured to output LOW) to under 1mA, well within any sink current spec of MCU. Eliminates any risk without any drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks @Ilya for the suggested design change. Would be implemented for the next iteration. Still would have been nice to known what was the failure mechanism.

Comment: What do you mean failure mechanism? The pin accidentally turns to output low, and you have 3.3V Vcc shorted through the MCU straight to ground. You have like 5A of current going through GPIO pin, so it burns. In other words, right now you can potentially kill or damage a microcontroller through software where there is no reason for it to be so. Just don't connect power lines to GPIO directly, there is no practical reason for it to be this way. And if you have an external resistor, you can always pull up, or remove the resistor or pull down for test or smth. It's better in every way.

Comment: Why would the pin turn to output low by accident? Well, it shouldn't and probably won't. But stuff can happen. Things get corrupted. Errors can happen. It's a software self-destruction button, which has no reason to be there, that's it. You will turn very low risk into zero risk at no practical cost (and let's be honest you can probably afford one more resistor).

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible.

Uninitialized pins are ***never*** in the output mode (in any STM32 uC) - only in input or analogue mode by default. So if your software did not change it - it is not possible 3.3V connected to the pin to damage the chip.

The only possible exception can be JTAG pins if they are in the state (they are in the alternate mode but I do not remember now if any can actually sink directly to GND) which can sing the current from the 3.3V.

## REMEMBER

It only applies if the code is working as expected. You show picture from the Cube, but your code might write something to the memory address occupied by the GPIOF registers changing it (for example you have not initialized pointer in your code).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The pin was to be probed to identify the mcu. And this probing would only be initiated after receiving  a specific message in the serial-bus. For the duration of power till failure the bus was disconnected and there is no chance that any code was run for this pin. Could you point me in a direction (reading material) which can help me see if wild pointer issue could have been a/the reason?  The pin under consideration does not have JTAG function, so the issue that might rise at reset/power-up could be ruled out.

Comment: @AnuragMohananTP Yes by default it is in HI-Z state. It cant short to the ground